# White Login Screen?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Whenever I boot up my mac,  I get a white login page with only my user on it. This started after I entered single-user mode to give myself admin (this is a school laptop... shhhhh ;) )

I can boot into it fine and everything, and it behaves normally, but they won't be able to log into their  I need to get this fixed so that they don't get mad at me for hacking my laptop.

Would [re-installing OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718) via <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> be the best option? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Enabling FileVault will change the color of the login screen. Check to make sure that you didn't enable FileVault at some point, and try disabling that to see if it resolves your issue.

see also http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10650

> Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, and then click Users & Groups.
>
> Click the lock icon to unlock it, and then type an administrator name
>   and password.
>
> Click Login Options.
>
> Choose an option from the “Automatic login” pop-up menu.

Comment: Linked KB article is gone. Does the white login screen appear once after enabling File Vault encryption, or forever after?